# Printed string showing up as undefined

Tags: javascript, function, loops, while-loop

I am trying to create a while loop inside of a function that will print out the phrase "I'm looping!" 3 times. I am having difficulties with it and the string is printing undefined. It is printing three times though. How can I get the string to print the phrase I want?

I am getting this error `Oops, try again. It looks like you're not printing the right string to the console.`

```
var count = 0;
var loop = "I'm looping!";

var loop = function(){
    while(count < 3){
        console.log(loop(count++));
    }
};

loop();
```

I have tried putting my loop variable inside the function. I have also tried putting the phrase `"I'm looping!"` inside of the loop(), like this:

```
loop("I'm looping!");
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've named *both* your string and function `loop`.  The 2nd declaration *replaces* your `loop` variable with a function; your string is gone.

You need to make sure to name each of your variables something different.  You also need to check what you are passing to `console.log()`.  You want to pass the *string* so it can be printed out.

```
var count = 0;
var loop_str = "I'm looping!";

var loop = function(){
    while(count < 3){
        console.log(loop_str);
        count++;
    }
};

loop();
```

Comment: Thanks! Why am I not able to do this though? `console.log(loop_str(count++));`

Comment: @Paul: What do you expect `loop_str(count++)` to do?  `loop_str` is a *string*, not a function.  Why are you trying to pass the `count` to `loop_str`?

Comment: So, doing this is declaring a function? `loop_str(count++)`

Comment: @Paul: No, doing this: `function(){}`, is *declaring* a function.  Doing `loop(count++)` is *calling* a function.

Comment: @Paul: `loop` is a function.  You call it with `loop();`.  `loop_str` is a string, it is not a function.  You cannot do `loop_str()`.  When you call a function, you can pass values to it as parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a function here :
You can print

```
"I'm looping"
```

3 times using just while.

```
var count = 0;
while(count < 3){
     console.log ("I'm looping") ;
     count++;
   }
```

Currently you are printing the return value of the loop function which is undefined since there is none.